# How does Qt's QHeaderView::saveState() and QHeaderView::restoreState() work?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to save tableview's column order and whether each column is shown. It looks like QHeaderView::saveState() and QHeaderView::restoreState() does what I want.

I've read the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#saveState) and [this example](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/28452/), but neither says what is saved exactly. I also tried to look up in the [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/tree/src/gui/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp), but did not find the implementation.

The reason I need to understand what is done underneath is that I am refactoring code that already saves column order and hidden column preferences. I'd like to make sure QHeaderView::saveState() and QHeaderView::restoreState() does exactly the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: Check [this part of the source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/aa863c61ec5e68ff73c02e25a2954cdba9c2ef15:src/gui/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp#L3505) to see what data is saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/tree/src/gui/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp#n3555) and [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/tree/src/gui/itemviews/qheaderview_p.h#n287) the following data is saved:

```
out << int(orientation);
out << int(sortIndicatorOrder);
out << sortIndicatorSection;
out << sortIndicatorShown;
out << visualIndices;
out << logicalIndices;
out << sectionHidden;
out << hiddenSectionSize;
out << length;
out << sectionCount;
out << movableSections;
out << clickableSections;
out << highlightSelected;
out << stretchLastSection;
out << cascadingResizing;
out << stretchSections;
out << contentsSections;
out << defaultSectionSize;
out << minimumSectionSize;
out << int(defaultAlignment);
out << int(globalResizeMode);
for each sectionSpan:
    out << size;
    out << count;
    out << (int)resizeMode
```